# How to get Custom post type by related category ID

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I have created a custom post types in function.php file.

I has created 4 categories on Service menu section, aa, bb, cc and dd, I try to get a latest 5 post for specific category but I can archive this.

this is my query post:

```
query_posts(array('showposts' => 5, 'post_type' => array('servicios'), 'cat' => 14));
```

14 is the id for category *aa* for example, I has tried *Tag_ID*, *category_name* and *term* instead *cat* and not work. What's wrong in my query?

UPDATE:

These are my argument right now:

```
$args = array(
  'paged' => 1,
  'posts_per_page' => '5',
  'offset' => 0,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_type' => array (
                    'servicios' => 'servicios',
                  ),
   'cat' => '15'
);
```

this is my generated sql query of wp_query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS mt24xi_posts.ID FROM mt24xi_posts 
    INNER JOIN mt24xi_term_relationships ON (mt24xi_posts.ID = mt24xi_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 
    AND ( mt24xi_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (12) ) 
    AND mt24xi_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page') 
    AND (mt24xi_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR mt24xi_posts.post_author = 1 
    AND mt24xi_posts.post_status = 'private') 
    GROUP BY mt24xi_posts.ID ORDER BY mt24xi_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

If I remove "AND mt24xi_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page')" the query work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days with this problem have resolved the problem, I fix it adding tax_query parameter with my taxonomy name and slug of the category requested:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array (
                    'servicios' => 'servicios',
                  ),
   'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'category',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => 'dgit'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

Create a new [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) or use pre_get_posts to modify an existing query.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'servicios',
    'category_name' => 'category-name'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Swap out category-name with the name of your category.

Comment: Doesn't work, If I use your query without category_name parameter (category slug) the query show all post for "servicios CPT", but when I set the category name in the query nothing is displayed. Ex: 'category_name'    => 'dgit' where dgit is my category slug

Comment: this is my generated sql query of wp_query:

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
 mt24xi_posts.ID FROM mt24xi_posts 
 INNER JOIN mt24xi_term_relationships ON (mt24xi_posts.ID = mt24xi_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 
 AND ( mt24xi_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (14) ) 
 AND mt24xi_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page')
 AND (mt24xi_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR mt24xi_posts.post_author = 1 
 AND mt24xi_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY mt24xi_posts.ID ORDER BY mt24xi_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
If I remove AND mt24xi_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page') work fine :S

Comment: @xzegga Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have updated the post with the code, thanks!

Comment: @xzegga Works as i tested it locally.